# how to merge an older revision to current working copy in svn

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Well, I merged a branch from trunk today which made many modifications of that branch disappeared, I knew something must be wrong with the way I did that merge. So I just want my modifications back from the revision just before that merge. How should I do it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not merge older revision. If `$REVISION` is totally bad and you want to discard changes, produced in it, you have to [reverse merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19526696/what-is-reverse-merge-revert-merge-in-svn-a-simple-explanation-and-the-step) `$REVISION` and get state of `$REVISION-1` as result