# Tortoise SVN: missing "Apply changes from this revision" option

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Imagine you have the following svn log:

```
Revision   Author   Date   Message
2163       Peter    ...
2152       John
2148       Peter
```

And that in revision 2163 you reverted the changes from revision 2152.
Is there a way to tell Tortoise SVN to apply the changes from revision 2152 only?

Comment: apply **when and to which** node? `merge -c REV` in common

Comment: @LazyBadger apply now and to my local checkout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Repository Log from TSVN context-menu, find revision, select it and from Log context-menu "Merge revision to..." (revision assumed in *another* branch, merge-target - your WC)

[image]

Comment: I've tried using that option, merging from `blah/trunk` to a local checkout of `blah/trunk`, and whether I got tree conflicts, or the merge completed without doing anything.

I tried showing the log from different levels, for example in a URL like `https://blah/trunk/foo/a.txt`, from `blah`, from `trunk`, and from `foo`; and choosing as destination `blah`, `trunk`, and `foo` respectively, in a local checkout `C:/blah/trunk/foo/a.txt`.

Comment: @rturrado - merge problems and errors are another question, unrelated to "how to merge"

Comment: You may be right. I may need to reformat the question as: how can I apply changes from a branch revision to a checkout of that same branch. I haven't been able to do it using the "Merge revision to..." option.

Comment: @rturrado - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25506790/merging-from-previous-revision-a-rollbacked-one

Comment: Thanks! I'm giving this answer as correct. People are warned that Tortoise SVN may fail applying changes from a previous revision, but you may end up reaching that with an svn command.