# How can undo commit on SVN with revision number?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have committed the code but i want to undo that commit, i have revision and branch number as well, i am unable to undo.

My clientis tortoise SVN, committed from IntelliJ Idea.
Please help.

Comment: agree with you @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: Your server IS NOT TortoiseSVN, TSVN is pure client!!! Start at least from SVN Book

Comment: mistakenly i write server @LazyBadger

Comment: You can also check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19526696/what-is-reverse-merge-revert-merge-in-svn-a-simple-explanation-and-the-step/19533227#19533227

Answer (score 1):

Please check the link. Describes rollback process.
http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-howto-rollback.html